# Can i generate reporting using google calendar

Tags: python, django, reporting, google-calendar-api

I am planning my all day activities in Google calendar LIke

1. Offcie time
2. sleeping
3. playing
4. Gym

I am happy with Google but issue is that i don't get reporting so that i can see how much time is spent in each category.

I know python and django so i was thinking is it possible that i still log all events in Google calendar and then i have daily cron jobs which will fetch events from Google calendar and then put in mysql database.

The main issue is i want to define separate categories for different things. Like WORK, SLEEP, SHOPPING etc.

But how can i do that from event name only. DO i need to enter some words in events whicg i can grab and make them as category. ANy ideas on that

Comment: I would suggest organizing these different things into own calendars,because that would be easier to detect than matching the title. Summing up all times in a calendar should be trivial. Have a look at [iCal-Analyzer](https://github.com/diN0bot/iCal-Analyzer), it might cover your needs.

Comment: Note that there is some reporting about google calendar in the [account activity report](https://www.google.com/settings/activity). It visualizes the time spend at home and at work, if you tagged the place correctly in google maps, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interseted in this:

http://www.gtimereport.com/

The gtimereport is a free online tool to extract your data from multiple google calendar to do time reporting. Looks clean.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers: if the lik is broken, the answer is not useful anymore. You can improve your answer by explaining the essence of the information at the linked address.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the input. I added some short information.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting link can be this one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably going to write a Python script for this soon.

I had written a reporting app before in C#, but it's badly written and I think Google has changed their API again so it's not working anymore.

The way I did it was to use tags. I wanted my total work hours per client. I would enter them into Google Calendar as: 
    @clientname description of work

Where clientname can be the first few letters only and the software matches it to a full name from a list of clients. My software would then allow you to chose a time-period and one or more clients and would output them into a neat looking Word file.

PS: to by honest the suggestion of using gtimereport.com seems very bad to me. You're basically uploading all of your calendars to strangers. That's why I'm going to write a script for this.